# Pass input data from component A to component B using React context

Tags: reactjs, components

My request is very simple:

Could you please provide me with an example where an input data is passed from component A to component B using context API.

Requirements: there should be an input value entered in component A. We send the input value over to component B using context.

A and B are sibling components.

Comment: I think it is possible only through their common parent

Comment: Well the parent would still be App.js for example

Comment: Do you have any shareable code on your try? or you can see my answer whether you are looking for the same solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

Make a function in Context.js state which set the state of your input field.

```
//context.js state

state = {
 inputFieldName: null,
 setInputField: ()  => {
    this.setState() //set value for inputFieldName here
 }
}
```

Call that setInputField function on onChange in component A using Context and you can get inputFieldName state from Context in component B.

Answer (score 0):

The required properties of the context:
1. A string property which stores the user's input
2. A method which updates the user's input.

And in your case the component A produces the input and calls the method to update it to context. The component B consumes the changes of the input from the context. it ends up with such a prototype.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const MyContext = React.createContext(null);

function A() {
  const { onChange } = useContext(MyContext);
  const [input, setInput] = useState(null);

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={input}
      onChange={e => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
        onChange(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
}

function B() {
  const { input } = useContext(MyContext);
  return <div>{input}</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(null);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ input, onChange: setInput }}>
      <div>
        <A />
        <B />
      </div>
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit stack-overflow/59081315/pass-input-data-from-component-a-to-component-b-using-react-context]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try, hope it will help you

**`componentA.jsx`**

```
import React from "react";
const ComponentA = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{`ComponentA: ${props.data}`}</h1>;
      <button onClick={() => props.onValueChange("value changed by ComponentA")}>
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentA;
```

**`componentB.jsx`**

```
import React from "react";
const ComponentB = props => {
  return <h1>{`ComponentB: ${props.data}`}</h1>;
};

export default ComponentB;
```

**`App.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ComponentB from "./componentA";
import ComponentA from "./componentB";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        data: "common value from parent"
    };

    handleChange = input => {
        this.setState({ data: input });
    };

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ComponentB data={this.state.data}></ComponentB>
              <ComponentA
                data={this.state.data}
                onValueChange={this.handleChange}
              ></ComponentA>
          </div>
    )}
}
```